# How to use "static final constant" in a Scala Constructor?

Tags: scala

I see this question: [Scala: public static final in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632138/scala-public-static-final-in-a-class) and this one, too: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/9178 but I can't make it work...

What I want to do is the Scala equivalent of the following Java code:

```
public class MyClass extends AnotherClass{

  public static final String WSDL = MyConfig.getProp("...");
  public static final String SERVICES = {new QName(MyConfig.getProp("..."))};
  public MyClass(){
    super(WSDL,SERVICES);
  }
}
```

What I tried, based on what I searched, is:

```
class MyClass (wsdl: String, services: Array[QName])(implicit val config:MyConfigClass) extends AnotherClass(wsdl,services:_*){
  val WSDL:String = config.getProp("...")
  val SERVICES: Array[QName] = Array(new QName(config.getProp("...")))
  def this() {
    this(WSDL,SERVICES:_*)
  }
}
```

But Scala IDE is telling me WSDL and SERVICES are unknown. Declaring WSDL and SERVICES at this point isn't supposed to be the equivalent for the Java MyClass.WSDL access?

Thanks for any solution, and for any explanation to make me scala more digestible...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala has no `static`. What you do instead is put everything that you would make `static` in Java, in the companion object of the class.

This is what your code should look like:

```
class MyClass (wsdl: String, services: Array[QName])
    extends AnotherClass(wsdl, services: _*) {
  def this() {
    this(MyClass.WSDL, MyClass.SERVICES)
  }
}

object MyClass {
  final val WSDL: String = "..."
  final val SERVICES: Array[QName] = Array(new QName("..."))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, I have another problem... WSDL is not just an hard-coded String but something like config.getProp("a property"), where config is an implicit value initialized in my App object. As an object can't be initialized with any params for what I see, how could I pass my config value to the companion object? I will edit my question...

Comment: @Cheloute How would you do that with static final variables in Java? Then you also can't depend on things that passed to your constructor.

Comment: @Jasper-M you're right, my problem is with my configuration implementation now.. Well, this solution is OK, so! Thanks!

Comment: This is not 100% equivalent: constants must be *explicitly* marked as `final val`, even if they are *implicitly* `final` by being declared in an `object` or `final class`. [The Scala Language Specification only guarantees constant optimizations for fields explicitly marked as `final val`.](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions)

Comment: @JörgWMittag More specifically, I think optimizations are only applied when the rhs of  the `final val` is a literal (or `classOf[SomeClass]` apparently), and no explicit type ascription is given to the `val`. Since OP is not assigning literals it doesn't seem to matter much anyway.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for the info, I've edited the code in my example.

Comment: You're confusing me, all... I thought that `val` was the equivalent of java `final`. Does final val mean that `final val arr = Array(1,2,3)` prohibits `arr(0)=4`, which could be possible without using `final`?

Comment: @Cheloute `val` is almost equivalent to Java's `final`, but there are some subtle differences as Jörg noted. About your question: no, `final val` does not make the array immutable. You can quickly test this yourself in the Scala REPL.

Comment: @Cheloute Java's `final` has multiple meanings, `val` is only equivalent to one of them, preventing reassigning variables.  `final` can also make methods non-overrideable and classes non-extendable.  So a `final val` is a `val` that you can't override in a subclass.